# Printing from apache to ubuntu 20.04 usb printer

Tags: 20.04, apache2, printing, php

I am using old ubuntu 12.04 with parallel port printer epson LX-310 (named epsonlx) and I am upgrading my old ubuntu with newer 20.04 with USB port (new computer do not have parallel port).  I have successfully print locally but I am unable to print from my apache webserver which is on another computer.

I am using this php command to print it:

```
copy($file, "//192.168.1.9/epsonlx");
```

Ubuntu install LX-310 printer automatically and I already make sure the ip is 192.168.1.9 and rename the printer to "epsonlx"
I check on the printer property and it is already shared by default.  Is there anything I need to do?  The $file is basically a php string type.

Thx!